# Push array value to the end

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
export interface mensajes{
     user:any
     msg:any
     day:any
     time:any
  }

    const [msgArray, setMsgArray] =  useState <msgX[]> ( [])


     setMsgArray([...msgArray, {user:props.email,msg:mensage, day:date.getDate()+"-"+date.getMonth()+1+"-"+date.getFullYear() , time:date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()} ])
```

that's the way to add a component at the end of the array. But how is it possible to add the component in the initial part of the array?

I need that

```
{user:props.email,msg:mensage, day:date.getDate()+"-"+date.getMonth()+1+"-"+date.getFullYear() , time:date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()}
```

is positioned at the first element and not at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just, well, put it at the start:

```
setMsgArray([{/* your new object here */}, ...msgArray])
```

Instead of putting it at the end, like:

```
setMsgArray([...msgArray, {/* your new object here */}])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the next state value depends on the previous value, it is recommended to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

Spread syntax (...) allows an iterable such as an array expression to be expanded in places.

here I created an example so you can observe and play

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-lichterman-3sxm3?file=/src/App.tsx